# How to write NON-CORE .NET with VS Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code and created a simple C# source. After installing OmniSharp and .Net Debugger extension, I want to start debugging the code.

VS Code asks me to `Select Environment` and by default there are `Node.js` and `.Net Core`.

I selected `More...` from the drop-down menu and tried to find an environment for standard .net framework (I mean the non-core version) but could not find any.

Does this mean VS Code only supports .NET Core?

Comment: There exists a debugger environment ".Net Console". Try that. If it does not work, you'd have to install dotnet core framework and make a project using "dotnet new console"

Comment: It's not showing up in the drop-down. Where should I specify that? in configuration file? or search for an extension?

Comment: Its usually defined under launch.json file. I'm not infront of my pc to tell u the exact steps. Try google, using my suggestion

Comment: I see "type": "coreclr". I think you are talking about that. thank you

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, non-core .NET functionality is nowhere to be found in any of the GUI drop downs on my configuration, while your mileage may vary in that respect, directly editing *launch.json* always works.  To convert an auto-generated dotnet core debug config to use non-core .NET, simply change the line `"type":"coreclr"` to `"type":"clr"`.  Here's an example configuration:

```
   {
       "name": ".NET Launch (console)",
       "type": "clr",
       "request": "launch",
       "preLaunchTask": "build",
       "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Project/bin/Debug/net461/Project.exe",
       "args": [],
       "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
       "stopAtEntry": false,
       "console": "internalConsole"
   },
```